# Get indoor position with bluetooth beacons with HERE SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, here-api, heremaps, here-maps-rest

Hey I am using the HERE SDK and we are trying to make it possible to track the position indoor. We have the indoor map set up on the here map inside the app (made in Flutter). Now we want the user to be able to move around and show the position on the map by using beacons. We receive the following information from the beacons
(using flutter-beacon for this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon):

```
// Example Output: {"region":{"identifier":"Minew Tech"},"beacons":[{"proximityUUID":"74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935","major":256,"minor":30313,"rssi":-99,"accuracy":12.77,"proximity":"far","txPower":-59,"macAddress":"84:EE:03:53:95:D0"},
// {"proximityUUID":"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0","major":0,"minor":0,"rssi":-75,"accuracy":0.28,"proximity":"immediate","txPower":-59,"macAddress":"AC:23:3F:A9:2E:7F"}]}
```

How can we use this information to update the position of the user on the map ?
Do we need to use this API:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/api-reference-swagger.html ?

Comment: I guess the main question is to get the geographic coordinates from your beacons. Then it should be straight-forward to set the position, see e.g. this example: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/positioning_app

Answer (score 0):

The Indoor Positioning service is not part of the HERE SDK but delivered through a separate SDK that can easily be used together with the HERE SDK. The Indoor Positioning service is not available for self-serve yet but requires the involvement of a HERE representative at this point in time.